# Display elements inline

Tags: html, css, styling

I was wondering if you could help.
I am looking for an easy way to display the circled elements in this picture https://db.tt/w5doYPNZ horizontally.

I have tried:

```
.calculator {
display: inline-block;  
}
```

However that doesn't seem to make any difference. I have added the HTML for reference.
Thanks in advance :D

```
<div class="calculator">
    <div class="input-group input-small">
        <h4>Adult (12+)</h4>
        <button class="btn theme-btn" id="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="adult" value="1" class="form-control input-usmall" min="0">
        <button class="btn theme-btn" id="increase" value="Increase Value">+</button>
        <h4>Child (2-11)</h4>
        <button class="btn theme-btn" id="decreasec" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
        <input type="text" id="child" value="0" class="form-control input-usmall" min="0" >
        <button class="btn theme-btn" id="increasec" value="Increase Value">+</button>
        <p>£</p><p id="total"></p><p>.00</p><button class="btn green" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here's a codepen with a working model.](http://codepen.io/erquhart/pen/kHFqb)**

The elements you're trying to affect with `display: inline-block` won't inherit that behavior from the `.calculator` parent element. You need to target them directly.

There's a lot I would change about your class naming and choice of elements, but at minimum, you need to create a separate class for calculator components, break the calculator structure into said components, and you need to convert your paragraphs to spans:

HTML:

```
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="calculator-submodule input-group input-small">
    <h4>Adult (12+)</h4>
    <button class="btn theme-btn" id="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
    <input type="text" id="adult" value="1" class="form-control input-usmall" min="0">
    <button class="btn theme-btn" id="increase" value="Increase Value">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="calculator-submodule input-group input-small">
    <h4>Child (2-11)</h4>
    <button class="btn theme-btn" id="decreasec" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
    <input type="text" id="child" value="0" class="form-control input-usmall" min="0" >
    <button class="btn theme-btn" id="increasec" value="Increase Value">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="calculator-submodule">
    <span>£</span>
    <span id="total"></span><span>.00</span><button class="btn green"     onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.calculator-submodule {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this stuff in it's own div:

```
<h4>Adult (12+)</h4>
<button class="btn theme-btn" id="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
<input type="text" id="adult" value="1" class="form-control input-usmall" min="0">
<button class="btn theme-btn" id="increase" value="Increase Value">+</button>
```

Then put this stuff it it's own div:

```
<h4>Child (2-11)</h4>
<button class="btn theme-btn" id="decreasec" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
<input type="text" id="child" value="0" class="form-control input-usmall" min="0" >
<button class="btn theme-btn" id="increasec" value="Increase Value">+</button>
```

Then this stuff in it's own div:

```
<p>£</p><p id="total"></p>
<p>.00</p>
<button class="btn green" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
```

Then float each of those divs. I would make the three newly created divs all live in the same parent div. Also, I would avoid display: inline-block, as it has issues in older browsers. Just float, and you get the same effect.

Comment: I disagree with this: `I would avoid display: inline-block, as it has issues in older browsers`. It works for all modern browsers, and for IE8+: http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block . And IE8 is available for Windows XP. I know no valid arguments to support anything older/worse than IE8.

Comment: Well, if you deal with international sites, you'll notice China is largely using IE6 still. I know. That's crazy. Also, IE7 is still used in other parts of the world including the U.S. You're right, though. inline-block works fine in modern browsers, but my point was specifically that - older browsers will break.

Comment: And Opera has major market share in Belarus etc. So? No one "develops for Opera", even though its market share is larger than IE7+IE6. I believe supporting IE7 and bellow does more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.input-group.input-small {
    display: inline-block;  
}
```

With this :

```
<div class="calculator">
                <div class="input-group input-small">
                    <h4>Adult (12+)</h4>
                    <button class="btn theme-btn" id="decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
                    <input type="text" id="adult" value="1" class="form-control input-usmall" min="0">
                    <button class="btn theme-btn" id="increase" value="Increase Value">+</button>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group input-small">
                    <h4>Child (2-11)</h4>
                    <button class="btn theme-btn" id="decreasec" value="Decrease Value">-</button>
                    <input type="text" id="child" value="0" class="form-control input-usmall" min="0" >
                    <button class="btn theme-btn" id="increasec" value="Increase Value">+</button>
                    <p>£</p><p id="total"></p><p>.00</p><button class="btn green" onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Too specific. What happens when he decides to use `input-medium` instead? This also drops the total related elements underneath the second input.